# Creating Custom Control in ios

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

i Want to Create a Custom Circle View.

I Have made a UIControl Sub Class, And Named as CircleView. i have applied Corner Radius to make look like Circle.

```
circleView  = [[CircleView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectmake(0, 0 , 200, 200)];
```

Next I have Imported to Root View Controller, allocated with frame to Show on My Root View Controller. So My Problem is ,

When i Touch to Corner of the View its Reacting to the Events.Why..? is That Possible add Events With in the Circle of Radius.

Answer (score 3):

A view is always a rectangle regardless of what shape you render within that rectangle.

To make your circle view only respond to events within the circle, you need to override the `hitTest:withEvent:` method.

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (/* point is within circle */) {
        return self;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```